# Нужны ли запятые в предложении: "Супесь песчанистая твердая непросадочная ненабухающая без примеси органических веществ малой степени водонасыщения"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Нужны ли запятые в предложении: "Супесь песчанистая твердая непросадочная ненабухающая без примеси органических веществ малой степени водонасыщения"?

Answer (score 2):

На предложение фраза не тянет. Расстановка знаков препинания зависит от значения применяемых терминов.
Возможные варианты:

"Супесь песчанистая твердая, непросадочная, ненабухающая, без примеси органических веществ, малой степени водонасыщения";

"Супесь песчанистая твердая, непросадочная, ненабухающая, без примеси органических веществ малой степени водонасыщения".

Comment: Это разные показатели грунта(супеси), так что первый вариант

Comment: Я тоже за первый вариант, потому что второй объясняет, что это примесь органических веществ плохо водонасыщается, а не песчанистая супесь.Кроме того запятые можно начинать ставить уже после песчанистая, возможно, супесь бывает ещё какая - то.